# Group by Use Query if SQL LEFT JOIN is performed multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

I think it's impossible, but I'm asking if there's a good way.

There are A table / B table / C table.

The table was joined LEFT JOIN based on table A with FK called id of each table.

At this time, I would like to output the count(*) as B table rows and C table rows based on `b.id(B_CNT)` `c.id(C_CNT)`

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID 
LEFT JOIN C ON A.ID = C.ID (base query)
```

how could I count group by b.id and c.id?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT B.ID), COUNT(DISTINCT C.ID)
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B 
ON A.ID = B.ID 
LEFT JOIN C 
ON A.ID = C.ID
```

(I couldn't quite understand from your question, but I'm making an assumption that you want the distinct count of "ID" from each table)

Comment: Don't we use the group by ?

Comment: It would depend on if there are other output columns that you want to include in your query.  My example will return the desired result without the need to specify a GROUP BY clause

Comment: For example, A table means Profile /  B table means Study_data1  / C table means Study_data2

So I have joined Like you

SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID LEFT JOIN C ON A.ID = C.ID

And I want to add count column group by b.ID and C.id

Result example (I wanted)
[ id ] [ name ] [ study_data1 count (group by b.id) ] [ study_data2 count (group by c.id) ]

Comment: You should probably amend your question to include this additional information, and also an example of the final data output that you're after.  That makes it easier for others to specifically address what it is that you're after.

Comment: In the case of what you're describing, then the query will probably be more like SELECT A.id, A.name, COUNT(B.id), COUNT(c.id) FROM Profile A LEFT JOIN Study_data1 B ON B.id = A.id LEFT JOIN Study_data2 C ON C.id = A.id GROUP BY A.id, A.name  - whether you include the "DISTINCT" in the count is up to how you want to see the results

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of scalar subqueries. For example:

```
select id, 
  (select count(*) from b where b.id = a.id) as b,
  (select count(*) from c where c.id = a.id) as c
from a
```